# Angular Firebase InitializeApp

Tags: angular, firebase

I've followed the angular [quickstart guide](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html) and have it running with no problems. I've then attempted to add firebase to my app as follows:

1. Install firebase from the npm repository using `npm install --save firebase`. This installed firebase v3.6.1 to `node-modules`.
2. Update SystemJS so the app can load the new firebase package, i.e., `systemjs.config.js` looks as follows:

   ```
   (function (global) {
       System.config({
   paths: {
       // paths serve as alias
       'npm:': 'node_modules/'
   },
   // map tells the System loader where to look for things
   map: {
       // our app is within the app folder
       app: 'app',
       // angular bundles
       '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
       '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
       '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
       '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
       '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
       '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
       '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
       '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
       '@angular/upgrade': 'npm:@angular/upgrade/bundles/upgrade.umd.js',
       // other libraries
       'rxjs':                      'npm:rxjs',
       'firebase': 'npm:firebase/firebase.js',
       'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api/bundles/in-memory-web-api.umd.js'
   },
   // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
   packages: {
       app: {
           main: './main.js',
           defaultExtension: 'js'
       },
       rxjs: {
           defaultExtension: 'js'
       },
       firebase: {
           defaultExtension: 'js'
       }
   }
    });
    })(this);
   ```
3. Then I update `app.component.ts` as follows:

   ```
   import { Component } from '@angular/core';
   import * as firebase from 'firebase';

   const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "xxxxxxxxxx",
    authDomain: "xxxxxxxxxxx",
    databaseURL: "xxxxxxxxxxx",
    storageBucket: "xxxxxxxxx",
   };

   @Component({
     selector: 'my-app',
     template: '<h1>Hello Angular!</h1>'
   })

   export class AppComponent {
    constructor() {
       console.log("Starting firebase");
       firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    }
   }
   ```

All other files remain the same as described in [quickstart guide](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html).

Now, when I try and run the app using `npm start`, I get the following error in the browser console:

```
Starting firebase
core.umd.js:2837 EXCEPTION: Error in :0:0 caused by: firebase.initializeApp is not a functionErrorHandler.handleError @ core.umd.js:2837
core.umd.js:2839 ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: firebase.initializeApp is not a functionErrorHandler.handleError @ core.umd.js:2839
core.umd.js:2842 ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:ErrorHandler.handleError @ core.umd.js:2842
core.umd.js:2843 TypeError: firebase.initializeApp is not a function
    at new AppComponent (http://localhost:3000/app/app.component.js:22:18)
    at new Wrapper_AppComponent (/AppModule/AppComponent/wrapper.ngfactory.js:7:18)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.View_AppComponent_Host0.createInternal (/AppModule/AppComponent/host.ngfactory.js:15:28)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.AppView.createHostView (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:9147:25)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.DebugAppView.createHostView (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:9407:56)
    at ComponentFactory.create (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:5481:29)
    at ApplicationRef_.bootstrap (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:6550:44)
    at eval (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:6459:93)
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at PlatformRef_._moduleDoBootstrap (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:6459:46)
```

Why is `initializeApp` not a function? (it appears to be there in `firebase.js`).

## Note:

WebStorm TypeScript intellisense is also complaining in `app.component.ts` that the `initializeApp` function on `firebase.initializeApp` is an unresolved JavaScript function. I don't understand this as there is a definition for `initializeApp` in `firebase.d.ts` packaged with the npm firebase package, i.e.,

```
declare namespace firebase {
  interface FirebaseError {
    code: string;
    message: string;
    name: string;
    stack: string;
  }

  ...

  function initializeApp(options: Object, name?: string): firebase.app.App;

  function messaging(app?: firebase.app.App): firebase.messaging.Messaging;

  function storage(app?: firebase.app.App): firebase.storage.Storage;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try calling firebase.initializeApp() from the app.module or whatever module you want to use Firebase in.

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to change library with **@angular/fire**. Please use the official library of firebase. Please refer [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/fire) link for the official library.

Then after in **app.module.ts** file you need to import **AngularFireModule** and initializeApp through this module,

**app.module.ts file**

```
import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebaseConfig)
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Then after put your firebase configuration into for development purpose environment.ts and for production purpose environment.prod.ts file

**environment.ts and environment.prod.ts file**

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  firebaseConfig : {
    apiKey: "XXXXX",
    authDomain: "XXXX",
    databaseURL: "XXXX",
    projectId: "XXXXX",
    storageBucket: "XXX",
    messagingSenderId: "XXXX",
    appId: "XXXX",
    measurementId: "XXXXX",
  }
};
```

For more information refer **[this](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/install-and-setup.md)** link. For this library documents refer **[this](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/tree/master/docs)** link.